# Different ways to express a misunderstanding

Tags: idioms

A common saying to express a misunderstanding in Italian is:

> - Prendere fischi  per fiaschi.

What are other expressions or sayings that can be used to convey the same concept?

Comment: I guess: "_prendere lucciole per lanterne_", "_prendere un abbaglio_", "_prendere un granchio_", "_prendere una cantonata_", "_fare una gaffe_", each with their different flavor and nuance in meaning and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to convey the meaning of a misunderstanding.

> *Ho frainteso*
>
> *Ho travisato*
>
> *Ho equivocato*
>
> *Ho capito male*
>
> *Ho fatto confusione*
>
> *Ho preso un abbaglio*
>
> *Ho preso un granchio*
>
> *Ho preso una cantonata*
>
> *Ho fatto una gaffe*
>
> *Ho preso lucciole per lanterne* (literally, *I mistook glow-worms for lamps*)

As they are used in different ways, it is advisable to consult a dictionary to identify the expression that best matches the intended message.

Answer (score 3):

I see already many suggestions, I could add also "qui pro quo" or "capire roma per toma" (the latter is very colloquial)

Comment: I've found this expression, "qui pro quo", in the book *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* by Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015) with an interesting explanation about its origin: «Nel medioevo il *quid pro quo* ("questo per quello") era il titolo di una lista di farmaci che si potevano dare al posto di altri. Da qui si è poi sviluppato il significato moderno di *fraintendimento*.»

Answer (score 2):

I've found in the book *Acqua in bocca! Tutto quello che vorresti dire in italiano... come lo direbbe un italiano!* by Roberto Bortoluzzi (Edizioni Casa delle lingue, Barcellona, 2015) that you can also simply say "si è trattato di un malinteso" o "è stato un malinteso". This is the example of usage that appears in this book:

> Si è trattato solo di uno spiacevole **malinteso**: non avevo nessuna intenzione di offenderti.